# Regard a couple of OR-RewriteCond directives if another RewriteCond evals

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following configuration,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.acme.com/$1 [redirect=301,last]
```

the purpose is to redirect to a canonical URL if the request is either not HTTPS, nor begins with www. or ends with .com.
For being seamlessly compatible with developer engines, I want to exclude *all* these directives if %{HTTP_HOST} includes, for example, `dev.internal` or so. In this case the RewriteRule should be skipped immediately. Since the three ORs are evaluated with the higher precedence than an (implicit) AND, I wonder how and where to place my `dev.internal` exception...
Thanks for any advice!

//edit: hmm... if OR has the higher precendence, shouldn't

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !internal\. [nocase]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https$ [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.acme.com/$1 [redirect=301,last]
```

work then?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of `ornext` is correct then yes, your way should work (can someone else confirm it?).

Here's another way, if you don't want to rely on that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} internal\. [nocase] # If it's an internal host...
RewriteRule .* - [skip=1]                    # ... skip the next rule (and leave the URL unchanged)

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https$ [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [nocase,ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.acme.com/$1 [redirect=301,last]
```